# How can I perform this integration in Mathematica?

Tags: numerical-integration

I am new to Mathematica.

I want to find the integration of the following expression:

$H(f)=T\left(\frac{sin(\pi f T)}{\pi f T}\right)^2$

Here, $T=1.127e-7$

I want to integrate this function for a for a set of upper and lower values of $f$.

For example,

```
   for i=1:20
       Integrate[H[f], {f, (i - 0.5)*val, (i + 0.5)*val}];
   end
```

Here, val=1000000;

Here is what i did:

```
      T = 1.127 e - 7;
      H[f_] := sin[pi*f*T]/(pi*f*T);
      Phi[f_] := T*H[f]^2;
```

Then how can I do the looping operation here.

Also, when I chose a particular value of $i$ and perform the integration, I do not get a specific value, instead I get an expression. Why is that?

Can anyone please help me to perform this integration in mathematica.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Please write your expression for `H` in Mathematica format.

Comment: Check documentation for `sin`. At the end you can use `Table` instead of `For`.

Answer (score 2):

Translating what you have:

```
h[f_, t_] := t*Sinc[Pi f t]^2;
t = 1.127*10^(-7);
val = 10^6;
NIntegrate[h[f, t], {f, (# - 0.5)*val, (# + 0.5)*val}] & /@ Range[20]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But I think it is better that you integrate symbolically the sinc^2 function and just evaluate it for different limits.

---

ref: comment. To do it symbolically

```
Clear[h, f, t]
h[f_, t_] := t*Sinc[Pi f t]^2;
anti = Integrate[h[f, t], f]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
t = 1.127*10^(-7);
val = 10^6;
(Limit[anti, f -> (# + 0.5)*val] -Limit[anti, f -> (# - 0.5)*val]) & /@ Range[20]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is not clear to me now if this is faster or not, since the antiderivative contains the sinIntegral in it. But you can time it and decide.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I do it symbolically? Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: @Dimitrios I updated answer